# Consulta sobre ejercicio Java, conexión a Base de datos Mysql

Tags: java, mysql, sql

Buenas noches compañeros, estoy realizando un curso de java (básico) y estoy trabado en un ejercicio que literalmente me esta volviendo loco no puedo encontrarle la solución. El motivo del hilo es consultarles si alguien me puede dar una mano. El ejercicio trata sobre conectarse a una base de datos Mysql, adjunto el código para ser más especifico:

```
package conectaBD;

import java.sql.*;

public class conecta_productos {

public static void main (String[] args) {

try {

// 1- Crear conexión



Connection miconexion = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3307/pruebas","root","1234");


Statement mistatement = miconexion.createStatement();


ResultSet miresultset = mistatement.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM PRODUCTOS");


while(miresultset.next()) {

System.out.println(miresultset.getString("NOMBREAR TÍCULO")+ " "+ miresultset.getString("CÓDIGOARTÍCULO")+ " "+ miresultset.getString("PRECIO"));
}

}catch(Exception e) {


System.out.println("No conecta!!");

e.printStackTrace();

}

}

}
```

Bueno, luego de haber copiado el código procedo a copiar el error que me da eclipse:

```
No conecta!!!
java.sql.SQLException: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
at mysql.connector.java@5.1.49-bin/com....QLErro r.java:965)
at mysql.connector.java@5.1.49-bin/com....MysqlIO.ja va:3933)
at mysql.connector.java@5.1.49-bin/com....MysqlIO.ja va:3869)
at mysql.connector.java@5.1.49-bin/com....MysqlIO.ja va:864)
at mysql.connector.java@5.1.49-bin/com....n(MysqlIO.java:1707)
at mysql.connector.java@5.1.49-bin/com....e(MysqlIO.java:1217)
at mysql.connector.java@5.1.49-bin/com....i onImpl.java:2189)
at mysql.connector.java@5.1.49-bin/com....ctionImpl.java:2220)
at mysql.connector.java@5.1.49-bin/com....i onImpl.java:2015)
at mysql.connector.java@5.1.49-bin/com....ionImp l.java:768)
at mysql.connector.java@5.1.49-bin/com....nect ion.java:47)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl .newInstance0(Native Method)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl .newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62 )
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessor Impl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl .java:45)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Construc tor.java:490)
at mysql.connector.java@5.1.49-bin/com....ance(Util.java:403)
at mysql.connector.java@5.1.49-bin/com....i onImpl.java:385)
at mysql.connector.java@5.1.49-bin/com....ingDriver.java:323)
at java.sql/java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager .java:677)
at java.sql/java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager .java:228)
at conectaBD.conecta_productos.main(conecta_productos .java:15)
```

Desde ya les agradecería mucho si me ayudaran, visito el foro bastante seguido y creo estar consultando en el lugar indicado. Buen comienzo de semana muchachos :)

Comment: Saludos. El puerto por default (he visto) es el 3306 veo tienes 3307; verifica lo estas poniendo correctamente; asi mismo que la instacia/servidor de MySQL este iniciada. Puedes probar por ejemplo con algun Software como SQL Maestro for MySQL, MySQL Workbench u otro de tu preferencia para realizar la prueba de conexión con los mismos datos; así corroborar todo esta bien en tu hacia tu BD.

Comment: El mensaje de error está indicando que el acceso ha sido denegado. Es muy probable que la clave del usuario `root` no sea `1234` cómo estás indicando. Eso lo puedes verificar por consola intentando entrar en la base de datos con algo como: `mysql -u root -p 1234` casi seguro que te dirá lo mismo. Tienes que saber por tanto cual es la clave de ese usuario. Muchas veces es un valor en blanco.